# Jquery mobile dynamic collapsible list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am facing a problem of dynamically adding a jquery mobile collapsible element. I have the following JSFiddle. There have been lots of questions similar to this one but I am not able to get the hang of it. I hope that someone would help me out as I am new to Jquery and finding it  a bit confusing at times.

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag1510/G6G9g/7/)

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="collapsiblelist" style="width:400px;height:600px; display:inline-  block;float:left">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
    var coll=document.getElementById('collapsiblelist');
   $(coll).append('<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" id="collapsible-set" data-ajax="false"></div>');
    $('#collapsible-set').append('<div id="collapsible1" data-role="collapsible" data-       collapsed="false" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b"> </div>');
    $("#collapsible1").append('<h3>first element</h3>');
    $("#collapsible1").append('<p>I am the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>');    
    $(coll).trigger('create');
```

The problem is that it appears on JSFiddle but not on my mozilla browser.

I have the same code.

Please inform me if i am missing any javascript files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to wrap code in `pageinit` or better, `pagebeforecreate`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G6G9g/8/

Comment: Thanx for the idea. Actually I noticed that I was using more than one jquery.js files of different versions in the html code. Once I deleted one it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use more than one jquery.js files. There could be a potential for code clash and elements may not be rendered even if your code is logically correct. Hope that helps anyone out there. Thanx guys